# プルタブの切り替えで特定のセルにジャンプすることは可能か（Google スプレッドシート・GAS）

Tags: google-spreadsheet

プルタブの切り替えで、特定のセルにジャンプすることは可能ですか？

添付画像の通り、週を切り替えることで、マウスホイールでのスクロール作業を省略したいです。（実際使っている計画表はもっと縦長です）

いちおう、色々と考えてコード書いたのですが、動きませんでした(^_^;)

お助け頂ければ助かりますm(__)m

[image: 添付写真]

**以下、コード**

```js
function onEdit(e){
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var editRange = e.range;
    //修正したところがG2以外の場合は終了
    if(editRange.getA1Notation() == "G2"){
        return;
    }
    //以下で現在のスプレッドシートの特定シートを指定し、○週目事に条件分岐
    //セルのアクティブは、.active()で
    switch(G2,"第1週目","第2週目","第3週目","第4週目")
    {
        //ケースゼロ
        case 0:
            spreadsheet.getRange('A20').activate();
            //ぜったい最後にbreakを入れる
            break;
        case 1:
            spreadsheet.getRange('A36').activate();
            break;
        case 2:
            spreadsheet.getRange('A52').activate();
            break;
        case 3:
            spreadsheet.getRange('A68').activate();
            //全てあてはまらなかたとき
        default:
    }
}
```

Comment: 「GASでブラウザを操作して特定セルへスクロールさせる」よりは、「特定セルへのリンクを（関数またはGASで）生成して、ユーザーはそのリンクを開いて移動する」のほうが簡単そうです。画面更新が必要になるかもしれませんが……

Comment: プルダウンメニューに拘らなければ、シンプルに「セル内の文字列リンクで別のセルにジャンプする」辺りであれば簡単に実現できそうです。

Comment: というかセル内にリンクを複数記してそれぞれでセルジャンプするようにすれば, マウスホバーで(プルダウンメニュー的な)リンク一覧が出ます